# Excel - find an remove everything except a specific string followed by 10 characters

Tags: excel, replace, find, wildcard, spreadsheet

I am trying to format my excel spreadsheet. One column in the sheet has a lot of extraneous data I need to get rid of, example:

> Product Dimensions: 11.1 x 10.3 x 2.5 inches ; 2 pounds Shipping
>   Weight: 1.6 pounds (View shipping rates and policies) Shipping:
>   Currently, item can be shipped only within the U.S. and to APO/FPO
>   addresses. For APO/FPO shipments, please check with the manufacturer
>   regarding warranty and support issues. Origin: Denmark ASIN:
>   B00C9X591Q Item model number: 6024464 Manufacturer recommended age: 7
>   - 12 years Amazon Best Sellers Rank: #111 in Toys & Games (See Top 100 in Toys & Games) #9 in Toys & Games > Building & Construction Toys >
>   Building Sets Average Customer Review: 4.8 out of 5 stars See all
>   reviews (298 customer reviews) Would you like to give feedback on
>   images?

I wan't to be able to find and delete all information in this list EXCEPT "ASIN: XXXXXXXXXX" I have been trying to use excel find and replace with wildcard expressions but have had little luck so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming the ASIN number is always the same length.

Add the following to a new cell =MID(A1,FIND("ASIN",A1,1),16)